# OpenGL/GLSL - Change viewing/model matrices for Glm Manipulation

Tags: opengl, glsl, glm-math

I can't seem to get my Square into the correct viewing Matrix in order to manipulate it using `glm`functions.

This is basically my `main.cpp` which consists of `init()` which loads a texture, glsl vert/frag files and constructs the square from the `ground class`. There is also a `reshape()` and `display()` function which calls `drawGround()` that renders the actual square.

Inside the `drawGround()` I've added the model/view matrices and done a small translation but it doesn't work... I've been playing with it for hours and can't seem to get it working....

```
void display()                                  
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawGround();
    glUseProgram(0); 
}

void drawGround(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(myShader.handle());
        GLuint matLocation = glGetUniformLocation(myShader.handle(), "ProjectionMatrix");  
        glUniformMatrix4fv(matLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &ProjectionMatrix[0][0]);

        glm::mat4 viewingMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0),glm::vec3(0,0,-1));
        ModelViewMatrix = glm::translate(viewingMatrix,glm::vec3(15.0,0.0,0));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(myShader.handle(), "ModelViewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelViewMatrix[0][0]);

    ground.render(texName, &myShader);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Yet on my other program I have the following function `renderSky()` which works just fine.
Please help me figure out where I'm going wrong...
If you need to see the Ground Class, let me know.

```
void renderSky(){
    glUseProgram(mySkyShader.handle());
    GLuint matLocation = glGetUniformLocation(mySkyShader.handle(), "ProjectionMatrix");  
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &ProjectionMatrix[0][0]);

        glm::mat4 viewingMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0),glm::vec3(0,0,-1));
        ModelViewMatrix = glm::translate(viewSkyMatrix,glm::vec3(15,0,0));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(mySkyShader.handle(), "ModelViewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelViewMatrix[0][0]);
    skyBox.render();

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in  vec3 in_Position;
in  vec4 in_Color;
out vec4 ex_Color;

in vec2 in_TexCoord;
out vec2 ex_TexCoord;

void main(void)
{
gl_Position =  vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
ex_Color = in_Color;

ex_TexCoord = in_TexCoord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the object into the correct Model/View space, it has to be multiplied against the `in_Position` in the vertex shader.

`gl_Position =  vec4(in_Position, 1.0);` becomes this:

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
```

Also, the Model and Projection matrices need to have uniforms added to the shader:

```
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
```

The vertex shader works with this additional code and allows the matrices to be manipulated by any following `glm` functions.